# How to jump to the end of a 'man' page

Tags: command-line, manpage

When I open up the manual for a command (`man wget` for example) the manual can be many hundreds of lines long. How can I get:

- to the end of the manual quickly and
- back to my terminal prompt?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When inside of the document viewer through the man command, press <kbd>h</kbd> or <kbd>H</kbd> in order to view the man's help.

From man's help screen:

```
JUMPING

  g  <  ESC-<       *  Go to first line in file (or line N).
  G  >  ESC->       *  Go to last line in file (or line N).
  p  %              *  Go to beginning of file (or N percent into file).
```

Another good idea would be to press the <kbd>Home</kbd> or the <kbd>End</kbd> keys. :)

Good luck!

Comment: Home, End, Page Up, Page Down, and the mouse scroll wheel all work as expected for me.

Comment: In the `man bash` interface, when I hit `g` and `G` I got to the top or the bottom, respectively.  What does the `< ESC-<` part mean?  I can type `g` then `7` then `<enter>` and it takes me to line 7, which is "line N" in the instructions but I couldn't tell you what made me try `g 7 <enter>` to get to line 7.  `p 50 <enter>` does take me to what I believe to be half-way through the document so I guess I understand some of it but what's `< ESC-<` all about?

Answer (score 5):

The normal ways to do this have been suggested (see [@geppettvs-dconstanzo's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/28791/22949)).  This leaves numerous unnatural, wrong, and bad ways.

So I'll deal with a couple of those.

---

First, you don't have to read the man pages from a terminal (even though it will make you a better person).  You can read them in html, for instance.

You can generate the html yourself from the sources on your system, but it's easier to go to [manpages.ubuntu.com](http://manpages.ubuntu.com) .

Here's the hefty `bash` page, turned into light and fluffy web-renderable html :
[The Bash Manpage from manpages.ubuntu.com](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/man1/bash.1.html)

---

Here's a hack that can actually be useful :  use `tail` to slice off some number of lines from the end of the man page output, and view that.

Least usefully, most trivally:

```
man bash | tail -100
```

might be useful :

```
man bash | tail -1500 | more
```

(or `man bash | tail -1500 | less`)

More useful (if contrived):

```
$ man bash | wc -l    # how many lines are in the man-page?
5375
$ man bash | tail -2600 | less  # jump to the middle of the output
```

---

Of course, this is what I'd do:

`man tac | tac | less`

(Although you might start out reading `man tac` forwards.)

Answer (score 4):

Some handy easy-to-remember *less* (and thus *man*) commands:

- <kbd>></kbd> takes you to the end of the file
- <kbd><</kbd> takes you back to the beginning
- <kbd>q</kbd> exits *less* / *man* (as noted by @Kwinto)
- <kbd>/</kbd> initiates typing a search term:

  - press <kbd>enter</kbd> to start searching
  - if you press  <kbd>enter</kbd> immediately, it searches for the next occurrence of the last entered search term
  - <kbd>n</kbd> also searches (forward) to the next occurrence
  - <kbd>N</kbd> searches backwards to the previous occurrence

Hope that helps (:

Answer (score 2):

- Press <kbd>G</kbd>
- Press <kbd>q</kbd>

You can type `man less` to get more information.

Comment: Man utility displays information with "pager", in Ubuntu default is "less", you can try "most" pager, it's has some cool features like displaying files in "windows", so you can view multiply file in one terminal, or even view several positions of a single file